# Is there any way to execute Hopper scripts from command line?

Tags: decompilation, hopper, script, command-line

What should I do if I have a batch of binaries to decompile with Hopper? 
I know how to run a Hopper script in the UI interface, is there any way to run Hopper scripts from command line? Or any other way to decompile a lot of files easily?

Comment: did you manage to achieve your goal? I have the very same need

Comment: @user2461515, no, I didn't find a way to use Hopper scripts. I used IDA and JEB3 instead.